# Compare and extract strings from list in python

Tags: python

```
LIST=['insert_job: aaa', 'box_name: bbb', 'insert_job: ccc', 
      'box_name: ddd', 'insert_job: eee', 'insert_job: fff', 
      'box_name: ggg']
```

In above list if there are 2 continous `insert_job: ('insert_job: eee', 'insert_job: fff')` then I want to print first `insert_job:` which in this case will be `insert_job: eee`.

Comment: Use a dictionary

Comment: already a dictionary named `LIST`

Comment: @Gang Um, it is a list.

Comment: a dictionary is {} and [] is a list!

Comment: Use `itertools.groupby`. What should happen if there are 3 continuous?

Comment: right, I was wrong, thanks

Comment: If there are 3 continuous then it should print first 2 and not print last one.

Comment: is it only for insert _job or also for box_name and the rest?

Comment: Just to be clear, you only want to print the first `n - 1` of any consecutive run. So when you see a single value, by itself with no matching neighbors, you don't want to `print` at all, right?

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran - yes only for insert_job

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - If no matching neighbour for insert_job then no action, if matching neighbour for insert_job then print first occurrence of insert_job.

Comment: @Frank If insert_job is repeated lets say 5 times then it should print 1st 4 insert_job with values -- this is your comment in yosemite_k's answer. What is that you want exactly!?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - I am new to this forum and will make a note of guidelines what you suggested.

Comment: This site is [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum), and not a free coding service either. Questions are expected to demonstrate some kind of research effort.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - Ok noted again and will follow as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

LIST = ['insert_job: aaa', 'box_name: bbb', 'insert_job: ccc',
        'box_name: ddd', 'insert_job: eee', 'insert_job: fff',
        'box_name: ggg']

for k, g in groupby(LIST, lambda s: s.split(':')[0]):
    if k == 'insert_job':
        items = list(g)
        if len(items) > 1:
            print(*items[:-1])
```

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger, I don't know why for the life of me I did it that way.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @- Steven Summers - I am new here and still getting used to with available options, i didn't realize that i made down vote, it was by mistake, i am trying to change it now but its not working.But i really appreciate your quick answer for this and this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: @Frank That's alright, you should be able to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

since you need the order of items, you don't need a dictionary. Try something as follows

```
seen = 0
for i in LIST:
    if i.startswith("insert_job"):
        if seen:
            continue
        else: 
            seen = 1
            print i
    else: 
         seen=0
         # print i
```

Comment: Mutating lists during iteration will not behave correctly in many circumstances, and repeated calls to `remove` mean `O(n**2)` work when this is trivially solvable in `O(n)`. This also destroys data from the original `list` when the OP's stated goal is filtering output, with no indication that the data should be discarded.

Comment: correct he doesn't need to remove items

Comment: I agree, push to a new list is not the best solution, but more clear

Comment: do you need to only print if insert_job is repeated, or all except repeated ones ?

Comment: If insert_job is repeated lets say 5 times then it should print 1st 4 insert_job with values

Comment: good, check the above code, it prints the first insert job in a contiguous insert jobs.